# visual studio 2013 ultimate crashing when writing to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have visual studio 2013 ultimate with update 4.
 when ever i'm writing in mvc project in the controller VS. is restarting .
I have tried to repair , I tried to uninstall and install again . 
I have no problem writing class ,view and so on .
I tried in new project, old project, always the same.
but Yuk (in safeMode from my Xml i'm getting this Error .

> Construction of frame content failed.
> Frame identifier: ST:0:0:{74946827-37a0-11d2-a273-00c04f8ef4ff}
> Frame caption: Server Explorer
> Exception details:
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid& packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid& context)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage()
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by "writing in mvc project in the controller", that doesn't even make any sense.  Are you talking about editing source code in the visual studio code editor?

Comment: i'm sorry that it's not clear ,yes, it's writing code in one of the I thing that it is sort of T4 in MVC project structure.

Comment: Have you tried running VS as Administrator?

Comment: Yes . I have tried running as admin